# Can't change button text on launching android swipe view app

Tags: android, view, swipe

I'm using eclipse and making an android app

I'm trying to have a saved setting for a button but when I try to set the button text when the app starts up it fails and i get lots of errors.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());


    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    LoadPreferences();

  .........

}private void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        floz = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("floz", false);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonVolumeType);
        button.setText("mls");
       }
```

if I delete the `button.setText("mls");` line it works fine

this is the logcat message

```
12-22 23:35:38.064: E/Trace(1384): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 12-22 23:35:38.663: D/AndroidRuntime(1384): Shutting down VM 
12-22 23:35:38.663: W/dalvikvm(1384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300) 
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cheapchug/com.example.cheapchug.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.example.cheapchug.MainActivity.LoadPreferences(MainActivity.java:260)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.example.cheapchug.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-22 23:35:38.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Did you already call setContentView?  If not, any search for an id will fail.  If you have, is that id defined in the xml you set as content view?

Comment: I've called setContentView but not with the xml that has the button on it. I'm using a swiping views with viewPager so there's a main.xml file and then tab.xml files for each tab and the button is in one of the tab files. The error doesn't occur if I add the button to main.xml fyi

Comment: if I put the load preferences() in `code`public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  LoadPreferences();
  
  return true;
 } `code` then it seems to work

Comment: thanks for the help. What was wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the onCreate Method the line `setContentView(R.layout.main);` loads only main.xml so the button hasn't been loaded yet and the button text can't be changed.
 but by the time `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` gets run the tab.xml files for the swiping view are loaded.